# Can't see my provisioning profile in Visual studio

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile, visual-studio-mac

I want to publishing my iOS app as AdHoc for testing, When I trying to signing the application in visual studio for Mac, The provisioning profile does not listed in combobox:

> No Matching Profile Found

I created a profile using my apple developer account, I followed [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=macos#download-provisioning-profiles-in-visual-studio) steps to download the provisioning profiles in Visual Studio without any error, the provisioning profile appears in the Provisioning Profiles list then I click `Download All Profiles` to download it.

Any suggestions!

Comment: Did you try to restart/update your VS? Here I found [similar thread here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92495/cant-see-my-provisioning-profile-in-visual-studio) and [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/xamarin-ios-provisioning-profile-not-showing-when/957696) you can refer to.

Comment: I used latest version of VS

Comment: Did you check this [reply](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/xamarin-ios-provisioning-profile-not-showing-when/957696#T-N990455)?

Comment: did you check to make sure that the bundle identifier matches, case included? I had that issue where I had Camel cased the identifier in the app, but it was all lower case in the apple developer account so VS would not recognize the profile